# Como esconder o ScrollBar, mas sem desativá-lo

Tags: jquery, rolamento

Gostaria de saber se tem como desativar o ScrollBar sem desativá-lo, ou seja, esconder o ScrollBar mas deixar ele funcionando normalmente, como se ele tivesse a mostra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para desativar a barra você usa o CSS sem segredo, como já deve ter tentando com o `overflow-x: hidden;`. O jQuery faz apenas a página ser rolável. Para tal, você pode usar o plugin `mousewheel` para **emular** a rolagem (nesse caso, apenas com o middle button). Para poder usar os botões direcionais e o pgdn, pgup, home e end, precisaria usar o eventos keydown e/ou keypress, ficaria um código um tanto mais complexo.

```
<div id="example" style="width:300px;height:200px;overflow:hidden">
    Seu conteúdo aqui
</div>

<script>
    $("#example").bind("mousewheel",function(ev, delta) {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
        $(this).scrollTop(scrollTop-Math.round(delta));
    });
</script>
```

Referência: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326570/how-can-i-disable-a-browser-or-element-scrollbar-but-still-allow-scrolling-with

Repositório do plugin MouseWheel no GitHub: [jquery-mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel)

Answer (score 5):

Existe um método muito simples, descobri no braço mesmo, simplesmente usando CSS, sem Js.
Coloque na sua folha de estilo:

```
/* Largura da barra de rolagem */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
}
```

Pronto :D

Answer (score 0):

Com CSS puro, você pode literalmente esconder a *scrollbar* de um elemento ao colocá-la dentro de outro elemento de dimensões menores. Sem *overheads*...

No exemplo abaixo, o `<div>` *#fixo* contém o `<div>` *#rolavel*, mas tem uma largura 17px menor e tem a propriedade `overflow` definida como `hidden`, garantindo que *#fixo* não "esticará" pra fazer caber a barra de rolagem do elemento filho. Enquanto isso, o `overflow-y: scroll` em *#rolavel* garante que haverá barra de rolagem no elemento filho, de forma que sua largura é sempre previsível independente do tamanho vertical de seu conteúdo.

Obviamente, para que o conteúdo seja rolável ele deve ser maior do que  elemento em que ele está contido (por isso o `height: 100px`). E claro, o mesmo efeito é possível na horizontal, com uso `overflow-x` e restringindo de acordo as dimensões de largura dos elementos envolvidos. Segue o exemplo:

```css
#fixo {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#rolavel {
  height: 100px;
  width: 117px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Role o div verde abaixo utilizando o scroll do mouse</p>
<div id="fixo">
  <div id="rolavel">
    <p>linha</p>
    <p>linha</p>
    <p>linha</p>
    <p>linha</p>
    <p>linha</p>
    <p>linha</p>
    <p>linha</p>
    <p>linha</p>
    <p>linha</p>
    <p>linha</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Uma alternativa utilizando apenas CSS:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Caso queira utilizar apenas em uma div/classe específica:

```
.scroll-hidden::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```